# find files that have number in file name greater than

Tags: linux, file, ls

If I have 10 files called 01-a.txt, 02-a.txt,...10-a.txt - how can I find the files where the number is greater than 5? I would like a general solution, and I would be putting the contents of all files into one file using something like

```
cat *.txt > bigfile.txt
```

I can get files with numbers using

```
ls *[0-9]*
```

but can't seem go beyond that.

thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may use `seq` for that, but it works only if all files have same naming convention:

```
seq -f "%02g-a.txt" 6 10
06-a.txt
07-a.txt
08-a.txt
09-a.txt
10-a.txt
```

I.e.:

```
cat `seq -f "%02g-a.txt" 6 10` > bigfile.txt
```

Comment: yes this works for me - I am getting the correct files - however combining with cat gives me cat: seq -f "%02g.txt" 6 10: No such file or directory

Comment: Please show full command -- it seems you have used incorrect quotation marks. You need to put `seq ...` part into grave accents (it used on SO for code formatting). You may also use bash `$(...)` syntax, i.e.: `cat $(seq -f "%02g-a.txt" 6 10) > bigfile.txt`

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the folder contains only these files.

This would list all files where the number is > 5

ls [0-9]* | awk -F '-' '{if ($1 > 5) print $0}'

Comment: Elegant, I like that one. The same can be used if someone needs to sort something by IP address.
Like IP's bigger than 10.10.125.x (from 10.10.126.0 on):  
`ls -1v 10.10.[0-9]* |  awk -F '.' '{if ($3 > 125) print $0}'`

Answer (score 3):

It will cat all files named as "< numeric_value >-< rest >" and having this < numeric_value > greater than `$LIM`.

Even if they are written with one single digit (like *5*), with two digits (like *05*), or more...

And even if the < rest > are different among the files.

```
LIM=5
for file in $(ls);
do
   number=$(echo $file | cut -f1 -d'-');
   [ $number -gt $LIM ] && cat $file >> bigfile.txt;
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ls *.txt | perl -n -e '$f = $_; $f =~ s/\D//g; $f > 5 and print'
```